# jQuery qrcode don't work with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, qr-code

There is a nice plugin QR Code: "https://github.com/lrsjng/jQuery.qrcode". In Firefox and Chrome works it successful, but in Internet Explorer 8.0 I got an error in Line:

The message for this line is: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

The complete code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/qrcode.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">                   
            $(document).ready(function(){     
                $('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");
            });                 
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>         
        <div id="qrcode" style="width:100px;height: 100px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Have everybody an idea?

Comment: It simply says "Object does not support this method or property"

Answer (score 3):

The website of the jQuery [QRCode plugin](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-qrcode/) has an [examples](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-qrcode/examples/basic.html) page that renders the QR code in both `<table>` and `<canvas>`.  The table option works in IE8, and you can use it instead of canvas for full compatibility (or you can code a toggle after checking the browser type and version).

Here's the example code to render the QR code in a `<table>` instead:

```
<script>
    jQuery('#qrcodeTable').qrcode({
        render  : "table",
        text    : "http://jetienne.com"
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this `QRCode` jquery plugin it depends on `canvas` object as it is not available in IE8 you might be getting this `error object does not support this method or property`.

When i debug this code i got the error on line

```
canvas.getContext('2d');
```

So, this plugin might not work in IE8

Comment: Like the first answer said, you just set the render to 'table', and it works in IE8!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in Internet Explorer 10 with canvas and it works without any problem...even when I select "Allow Blocked Content" the QR code is also displayed in Internet Explorer 8.